# Android Studio | Build failed with an exception

Tags: android

I have this problem:

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/j.castellanos.molina/StudioProjects/App_01/android/build.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file '/Users/j.castellanos.molina/StudioProjects/App_01/android/app/build.gradle' (/Users/j.castellanos.molina/.gradle/caches/6.7/scripts/19qdieppdvoa9l8ackxz7ozkm).
> > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 62

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I have no idea how I can fix this, can you help me.

Comment: The exception has more than one cause. Maybe you could share what you did that might lead to the exception.

Comment: Try to clear the cache and rebuild from the file->clear cache and rebuild option.

Comment: 0

Open the Gradle settings and change the Gradle JVM to the same JDK version you are using.